# Add app settings to web.config with Octopus Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, octopus-deploy

We have started using Octopus Deploy for our ASP.NET Mvc 5 websites and replacing web.config values is working really well but is there a way to add values to the web.config that don't exist?

The reason we need to do this is we have a pluggable architecture and some projects are not referenced by the solution and these additional projects are packaged up as NuGet and there is an additional step that if the machine is in a particular role these extra packages are deployed and the app loads the dlls when it starts.

However the standard web.config we deploy doesn't have these settings in and we don't want to add additional values if not needed so being able to add more appsettings to the web.config on deploy would be ideal.

Comment: could you explain how do you update a value in the web.config with octopus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about doing this in Octopus Deploy.

If you know the sections you want to add ahead of time it you could use [Conditionals](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variable+Substitution+Syntax) to include or exclude sections in conjunction with [web config transformations](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files).

If you need to do something more dynamic the best approach is to use a `deploy.ps1` PowerShell script to add the nodes. Something like this would do it.

```
$filePath = [path to my web.config file]

# load the XML from the web.config
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

$setting = $xml.CreateElement('add')
$setting.SetAttribute('key','Name')

$xml.configuration.appSettings.AppendChild($setting)

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this code snippet helped me write the powershell script we needed.